# Ion Refresher color change on diferents pages of Ionic4/5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, spinner, ionic5, refresher

I have an app with different pages, every page has a different emphasis color

I need to change the IonRefresher color to match with it, but i only found info about change it globally adding the follow code to **global.scss** file:

```
ion-refresher.refresher-native ion-spinner{
    color: var(--ion-color-secondary) !important;
}
```

There is no info of coloring on the oficial [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more then one page and you want to match spinner color with the page color you can but you will have to specify this on the `global.scss`. you can create as much spinner color as you want. and you can use them by the CSS class. I have shared HTML and CSS code for it below please have a look

**global.scss**

```
 .red.refresher-native{
   ion-spinner{
      color: red!important;      
   }

   .arrow-container ion-icon{
      color: red!important;   
   }
} 

.green.refresher-native{
   ion-spinner{
      color: green!important;      
   }
   .arrow-container ion-icon{
      color: green!important;   
   }
} 
.purple.refresher-native{
   ion-spinner{
      color: purple!important;      
   }
   .arrow-container ion-icon{
      color: purple!important;   
   }
}
```

**html code**

```
//Change class name as per your requirement 
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" class="red">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>

<ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" class="green">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

Comment: Excelent, this work almost perfectly. Now i have to deal with the arrow in front of the pulling-icon, wich not change it color. Tanks!

Comment: can you show me which icon you are talking about

Comment: Shure, i make a gif here [link](https://hnet.com/video-to-gif/viewimage/20210125-00-mKkN9TRk4RBOQZU4-XnoBss-HNET). When i pulling the arrow in front doesn't change it color, but the spinner does

Comment: that'll be awesome @taylor-rahul

Comment: i have edited my answer you can use the updated css for arrow color change